# Laravel cannot find a Controller Method

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

> Method App\Http\Controllers\CommunityController::show does not exist

My route

```php
Route::get('/community/{id}', [CommunityController::class, 'community'])
    ->name('profile.community');
```

Controller

```
public function community($id)
{
    $communityProfile = Community::find($id);
    /* $join = CommunityUser::join('communities', 'communities.user_id', '=', 'community_users.user_id')->get(); */

    return view('user.comprofile', compact('communityProfile', 'join'));

}
```

View community

```html
@for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
    <a href=" {{ route('profile.community', $communities[$i]->id) }} ">
        <div class="w-full p-6 overflow-hidden bg-white border hover:bg-gray-50 border-gray-200 rounded-lg shadow-md dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
            <h5 class="mb-2 text-2xl font-semibold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white">{{$communities[$i]->community}}</h5>
            <p class="mb-3 font-normal text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 flex gap-3">
                <x-iconsax-out-location class="text-[#F15E4A] w-5"/> {{$communities[$i]->address}}, {{$communities[$i]->city}}
            </p>

            <div class="flex gap-2">
                <a href="#" class="inline-flex items-center font-semibold text-[#F15E4A] hover:underline cursor-default">
                    {{ $communities[$i]->type }}
                </a>
                
                @if ($communities[$i]->user_id === Auth::user()->id)
                    <span class="text-sm text-gray-500 pt-1">{{__('Created by: ')}}</span>
                    {{Auth::user()->name}}
                @else
                    <span class="text-sm text-gray-500 pt-1">{{__('Created by: ')}}</span>
                    {{ $communities[$i]->name }}
                    
                @endif

            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
@endfor
```

I am trying to view the community created by users but it gives me "cannot find a Controller Method ".

Comment: Did you have any resourse route related to CommunityController?

Comment: Your error message is `Method App\Http\Controllers\CommunityController::show does not exist`, but you posted code that is using `community`, not `show`. Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75250647/edit) and clarify that? Is that a typo? Do you have a `show` method? Are you trying to use it? Needs more details please and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can have several causes. Therefore, here is a small checklist:

1. The controller path is missing from your route:

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\CommunityController; // this line
Route::get('/community/{id}', [CommunityController::class, 'community'])->name('profile.community');
```

2. Your CommunityController class name is misspelled
3. The namespace of the CommunityController is wrong

And then just to be sure, run: `php artisan route:clear`.

Comment: those would all cause a class not found error